# Ngrok having ridiculous latency

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, video-streaming, ngrok

I've been trying to stream video from my robot to my local machine over the internet. I've setup a simple test to capture video from a raspberry pi and send it via a socket to my local machine. I have a ngrok tunnel forwarding to my machine and the robot connects through the tunnel. I'm new to networking so feel free to criticize.

The issue I'm having is ridiculous latency and lags, I'm talking into the 10s of seconds. Doing the tests I've noticed some patterns:

- If I run everything in the local wifi, latency is very low. Streaming over the actual internet induces huge latency
- The ngrok tunnel started out with ~50ms latency, but when I start the video stream it can go up as bad as ~10000ms!
- the latency seems to increase when I have lots of motion on the camera

client(robot):

```
import socket, cv2
from struct import pack, unpack, calcsize
import threading
from time import sleep
from base64 import b64encode
from imutils import resize

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
client_socket.connect(('4.tcp.eu.ngrok.io', 13114))

def capture_vid(sock):
    vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 1)
    while (vid.isOpened()):
        try:
            _, frame = vid.read()
            frame = resize(frame, width=480)
            encoded, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame, [cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 60])
            msg = b64encode(buffer)
            message = pack("Q", len(msg)) + msg
            sock.sendall(message)
        except:
            print('SERVER DISCONNECTED')
            break
        sleep(0.06)


stream_thread = threading.Thread(target=capture_vid, args=(client_socket,))
stream_thread.start()
```

server:

```
import socket, cv2
import threading
from base64 import b64decode
from struct import pack, unpack, calcsize
import numpy as np

class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        self.server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server_socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
        host_name = socket.gethostname()
        host_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host_name)
        print('HOST IP:', host_ip)
        port = 9998
        socket_address = ('localhost', port)

        # Socket Bind
        self.server_socket.bind(socket_address)
        self.client_socket = None

    def listen(self):
        self.server_socket.listen(5)
        client_socket, addr = self.server_socket.accept()
        self.client_socket = client_socket
        print('GOT CONNECTION FROM:', addr)

        data = b""
        payload_size = calcsize("Q")
        while True:
            try:
                while len(data) < payload_size:
                    packet = self.client_socket.recv(1024)
                    if not packet: break
                    data += packet

                packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
                data = data[payload_size:]
                msg_size = unpack("Q", packed_msg_size)[0]
                print(msg_size)
                while len(data) < msg_size:
                    data += self.client_socket.recv(64 * 1024)
                frame_data = data[:msg_size]
                data = data[msg_size:]
                #frame = pickle.loads(frame_data)
                frame = b64decode(frame_data, ' /')
                npdata = np.frombuffer(frame, dtype=np.uint8)
                frame = cv2.imdecode(npdata, 1)
                cv2.imshow("RECEIVING VIDEO", frame)
                key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
                if key == ord('q'):
                    break
            except:
                print("client disconnected")
                break
        client_socket.close()

server = Server()
server.listen()
```

huuuugeee latency on ngrok:

[image: 1]

I've tried increasing buffer, some tricks on cv2.CaptureVideo() but to no avail. What else can I do to minimize lags/ latency? (i'm open to any solution, paid ones included) How does zoom/messenger achieve such low latency and smooth video calls?

*Note: many have asked similar questions about streaming video with raspi before. But most are trying to stream locally over wifi as a ip camera. I'm trying to stream over the public internet directly to my machine and not to a browser.

UPDATE:

Not an answer but I've done some analysis. I still hope an expert can point out the problem.

Test 1: streaming video over wifi in the local network only: Video stream is smooth with little to no latency. I'm not doing any image processing so I don't think internal processing speed is a problem.

Test 2: Facebook video call through messenger. Upload speed measured with Bitmeasure OS.

Test 3: My own video stream over a ngrok tunnel on my laptop, same camera. Bad latency and fps.

On the left is test 3, and on the right is test 2.

[image: Left: test 3, right: test 2]

As you can see, my connection looks to be fluctuating quite a lot. The low download rate for test 2 is due to the video stream coming from a phone with lower resolution, but that I think is irrelevant. In both cases, the average upload speed seems to be about the same.

I've also tested the actual size of each frame by adding a simple line that prints out the length of the received frame data. When I do no resizing, it comes out to be about ~170KB, and with resizing down to 480p about ~30kB. But even at 30KB per frame the stream suffers.

My questions are:

- Is the fluctuating upload speed the reason behind the lag?
- What causes the problem and of course,
- what can I do to fix it?

Update 2:

After further digging it seems to be the amount of data I'm trying to transfer that is causing the problem. I went to a place with good internet connection and the stream went up to ~800kB/s, but still nowhere facebook-smooth. I'm guessing the combination of opencv capture/encoding being inefficient and tunneling makes for huuugeee overheads... What other options do I have?

Comment: The reason seems to be bandwidth rather than simple latency. Using ngrok your data will be sent from your robot to some ngrok server in the world and back to your local machine. The bandwidth bottleneck can be anywhere in between. ngrok my limit the bandwidth for free accounts. Often the upstream rate of your local internet connection is very limited. Did you check all  this?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
I fixed it! The problem was the 64 * 1024 buffer I was trying to receive:

```html
while len(data) < msg_size:
                    data += self.client_socket.recv(64 * 1024)
```

I was under the impression that bigger buffer is better - not in this case. The way I have it here, I'm essentially forcing 64kB to load every time the while loop is executed. The network cannot handle that and the connection suffers.

The correct way is actually set the buffer really low - so that the network slowly trickle in the bytes. 256 bytes works well in my case - yes, only 256 bytes. It's like squeezing water in a bottle through a hole, if you let it trickle, you're good, but if you squeeze too hard, you suffer.

That is as far as I understand it, I'm no way an expert on this but the solution worked. If anyone have a better way of phrasing this, I'd like to hear too.